# Icons are not showing in navbar

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

Hi so this is my navbar that i created with some icons that navigate between screens when i press them , the icons looks fine on my project with expo  (without Android and ios folders)
[image]

this is my code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import EmptyHistory from '../Accueil/EmptyHistory.js'
import Profile from '../Accueil/Profile.js'
import Accueil from '../Accueil/Accueil.js';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
            initialRouteName="Accueil"
            activeColor="#D05A0B"
            
            
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Historique"
                component={EmptyHistory}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Historique',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="history" color={color} size={26} />
                    ),
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Accueil"
                component={Accueil}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Accueil',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="food" color={color} size={26} />
                    ),
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Profile"
                component={Profile}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={26} />
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MyTabs/>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

So i switched my project using npx react-native (with Android and ios folders) and i did all the installs including the vector icons

[image]

[image]

but the results are not the same , my icons are not showing properly in my navbar
[image]

is there any solution for this ?

Comment: I guess you are using 'react-native-vector-icons', Have you linked your library ?. try react-native link

Answer (score 0):

To install icons in bare react native is as same as putting new fonts in react native, so you can follow this https://mehrankhandev.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4